# Не работает сетка бутстрапа

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: При обычном разрешениее]Вернее, он работает, но не так как я хотел бы.
Я задаю блокам, которые стоят в `.row` классы:
1) `.col-xs-12 .col-md-4`
2) `.col-xs-12 .col-md-6 .col-md-offset-2`
При масштабировании страницы блоки выстраиваются в колонку и занимают всю ширину, но когда открывюа в панели разработчика и выбираю какой-либо смартфон, они просто сжимаются.

Что не так?[image: При уменьшенном разрешении]

Comment: какую версию bootstrap-а вы используете ?

Comment: Масштабирование это совершенно другое, это не медиа запросы на которых построрен бутсрап. Без кода больше ничего нельзя сказать. Куда именно и почему вы смотрите без скринов сопровождающих тоже можно догадываться только. Добавьте [mcve] кода, приложите скрины, опишите более конкретно что и при каком разрешении и при каком масштабировании(а это 2 разные вещи) вы желаете увидеть

Comment: Сочетания масштабирования и разных размеров, может давать совершенно неожиданные варианты. Убираете ли вы масштабирование, когда открываете панель разработчика? тоже имеет значение

Comment: @kizoso Добавил картинки, там два блока с классами при нормальном и уменьшенном разрешении

Comment: @Избытоксусликов 3

Comment: Как насчет того что бы построить сетку исходя из документации bootstrap.
container>row>col